# How to fix errors while installing in magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database, theme, installation

My Theme Name : **Milano - Fashion Responsive Magento 1 & 2 Theme**

Version : **Version 2.1.3**

Hi All,
 I install milano theme in magento 2 while i installing this theme the process was stopped in 27%.
 I have attached the screenshot of my error

[image]

The theme has two type of installation
1.**Install quickstart** - By using this package, you will set the theme exactly as our Demo with sample data.
2.**Install only template** - If you exist a magento website you can install only template.

I am using **quickstart** method so they give magento with theme file and database also using this files only i install

Is there any solution for this type of error?

Comment: Lets install only template. I think they may have got something wrong in demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the demo I saw there are 3 languages which means at least 3 store views, possibly even more. Apparently by installing using quickstart method, you also get content for all other store views. 
Apparently the installer is trying to retrieve a non-existing store view. You could either:

- Create more store views prior to installation or
- Install the templates only